# How to set the rotation center of a nested SVG

Tags: css, svg, css-transitions

I want to rotate a nested SVG element (a polyline) around it's center which is not (0,0).
The rotation is animated (transition), and as I want to trigger it with a style, I have written a 'standart' CSS transition (I mean it's not a SVG animation, I suppose it would be the same thing ?).

One other thing : the SVG is resized by the container  and it's `viewBox` attribute as you can see :

```
<div id="container">
    <svg version="1.1" id="svghook" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-1 0 2 20">
        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="20"></line>
        <circle cx="0" cy="10" r="1" stroke-width="0px"></circle>
        <polyline id="svghookbutton" points="0.4,9.6 -0.5,10 0.4,10.4 "></polyline>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Now I want to rotate the polyline and tried this :

```
transform: rotate(180deg);
transform-origin: 0px 10px;
```

(0, 10) is the center of the rotation before scaling.

Finally the polyline is rotated, but it makes a very strange fly .. [you can see it in this fiddle if you hover the '>' in the black circle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeum/e0fokgkh/).

What is wrong in this sample ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution:

1. Move transform-origin to #svghookbutton (not on hover state).
2. Change `#svghookbutton:hover` selector to `#svghook:hover #svghookbutton`, because with your selector when your arrow is rotating mouse cursor looses contact with arrow and it stops your transition. The selector I recommend you begin the transtition when you hover over the black circle.

[Fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/e0fokgkh/4/)

Comment: Great! I thought that 'transform' and 'transform-origin' had to be in the same style. Thanks... Did you remove useless prefixed styles ?

Comment: Yes, you need only webkit and ms (if you support IE9).

Comment: Actually the style is set by js, otherwise it should be triggered by the black circle indeed. Thanks.